# Strange Roundrobin Style Sorting Algorithem Name

Tags: python

I have been using the more_itertools `roundrobin` function to "fairly" distribute to workers. (literal ones, not Celery)

which would look like this.

`list(roundrobin('AAA', 'BB', 'CC')) == ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A']`

This all looks well and good to me, but the client has said that this isnt "even" enough.

The output he is wanting is as follows `['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A, 'B', 'C']`

He is wanting the order not to sample ALL the other elements before going back to a duplicate.

`roundrobin` is based around `interleave_longest` and apparently interleave_longest will sample from all the lists before going back around to the duplicates.

As for my question, *what* is this process even called? Is there a Python function for it or is it something to roll out on my own? Is it even statistically viable to do this method while maintaining "fairness"?

Comment: You're going to have to work out your client's requirements with your client. One example isn't enough for us to tell you what they want or how to implement it.

Comment: @user2357112 in that post, those are his requirements. i shouldnt have said 'appears'.
but what that sorting method is , i have no clue.

Comment: Again, this isn't enough information to go off of. If this is all the information your client gave you, you need to go have a conversation with your client and get more information.

Comment: You need to describe the general relationship between input and output. One example isn't enough to extrapolate from.

Comment: His words are "it needs to be more even like it is on our spreadsheet" lol
what he's referring to i belive is that this distance between duplicates is as "distributed" as possible. ill edit with any other info he gives. @user2357112